# Convolving a periodic image with python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, convolution

I want to convolve an n-dimensional image which is conceptually periodic.

What I mean is the following: if I have a 2D image

```
>>> image2d = [[0,0,0,0],
...            [0,0,0,1],
...            [0,0,0,0]]
```

and I want to convolve it with this kernel:

```
>>> kernel = [[ 1,1,1],
...           [ 1,1,1],
...           [ 1,1,1]]
```

then I want the result to be:

```
>>> result = [[1,0,1,1],
...           [1,0,1,1],
...           [1,0,1,1]]
```

How to do this in python/numpy/scipy?

Note that I am not interested in creating the kernel, but mainly the periodicity of the convolution, i.e. the three leftmost ones in the resulting image (if that makes sense).

Comment: I think you'll have to roll your own code, pretty easy using FFTs and the [convolution theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem). The only tricky part could be how to pad the kernel to get the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of 'periodic convolution' is better known as circular or cyclic convolution. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_convolution.

In the case of an n-dimensional image, as is the case in this question, one can use the scipy.ndimage.convolve function. It has a parameter *mode* which can be set to *wrap* for a circular convolution.

```
result = scipy.ndimage.convolve(image,kernel,mode='wrap')

>>> import numpy as np
>>> image = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
...                   [0, 0, 0, 1],
...                   [0, 0, 0, 0]])
>>> kernel = np.array([[1, 1, 1],
...                    [1, 1, 1],
...                    [1, 1, 1]])
>>> from scipy.ndimage import convolve
>>> convolve(image, kernel, mode='wrap')
array([[1, 0, 1, 1],   
       [1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: [scipy.signal.fftconvolve](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.fftconvolve.html) does not support the `'wrap'` mode.

Comment: No, but it performs a circular convolution.

Comment: It doesn't do circular conditions on my system, not with any of the modes listed in the documentation.  Just be sure to test any of these with a sample before use on data.

Answer (score 4):

This is already built in, with `scipy.signal.convolve2d`'s optional `boundary='wrap'` which gives periodic boundary conditions as padding for the convolution.  The `mode` option here is `'same'` to make the output size match the input size.

```
In [1]: image2d = [[0,0,0,0],
    ...            [0,0,0,1],
    ...            [0,0,0,0]]

In [2]: kernel = [[ 1,1,1],
    ...           [ 1,1,1],
    ...           [ 1,1,1]]

In [3]: from scipy.signal import convolve2d

In [4]: convolve2d(image2d, kernel, mode='same', boundary='wrap')
Out[4]: 
array([[1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1]])
```

The only disadvantage here is that you cannot use `scipy.signal.fftconvolve` which is often faster.

Answer (score 3):

```
image2d = [[0,0,0,0,0],
           [0,0,0,1,0],
           [0,0,0,0,0],
           [0,0,0,0,0]]
kernel = [[1,1,1],
          [1,1,1],
          [1,1,1]]
image2d = np.asarray(image2d)
kernel = np.asarray(kernel)

img_f = np.fft.fft2(image2d)
krn_f = np.fft.fft2(kernel, s=image2d.shape)

conv = np.fft.ifft2(img_f*krn_f).real

>>> conv.round()
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.]])
```

Note that the kernel is placed with its top left corner at the position of the 1 in the image. You would need to roll the result to get what you are after:

```
k_rows, k_cols = kernel.shape
conv2 = np.roll(np.roll(conv, -(k_cols//2), axis=-1),
                -(k_rows//2), axis=-2)
>>> conv2.round()
array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```